# Inserting record into 2 join tables for same entities in Fluent API EF5

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-5

How can I insert into two join tables with the below entities and query based on the single join table.

This is my scenario :

```
public class Customer 
{
  public Customer()
  {
     Tickets=new List<Ticket>();
  }

  public int CustomerId { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets {get;set;}
}

public class Ticket 
{
  public Ticket()
  {
     Customers=new List<Customer>();
  }
  public int TicketId { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers {get;set;}
}
```

Whenever mapping is done, inserting into 2 join tables :

1) Customer Ticket table

2) Person Ticket table

and can be able to query based on the any join table? Right now,I can only insert record into one single join table ( Customer Ticket table)

Comment: is `Customer : Ticket = M :M` ? can you show the insert query also?

Comment: Yes,it is Many to Many